# How to use XmlReader class?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I want to save and load my xml data using XmlReader. But I don't know how to use this class. Can you give me a sample code for start?

Comment: Yes, but that's what StackOverflow is for, too!

Comment: XmlReader is the Reader used by POCO Entites tt to read the edmx file. So to continue with their API, and use it correctly, and not parse the emdx file by myself I need to used XmlReader.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally I have switched away from XMLReader to System.XML.Linq.XDocument to manage my XML data files. This way I can easily pull data from xml into objects and manage them like any other object in my program. When I am done manipulating them I can just save the changes back out the the xml file at any time.

```
        //Load my xml document
        XDocument myData = XDocument.Load(PhysicalApplicationPath + "/Data.xml");

        //Create my new object
        HelpItem newitem = new HelpItem();
        newitem.Answer = answer;
        newitem.Question = question;
        newitem.Category = category;

        //Find the Parent Node and then add the new item to it.
        XElement helpItems = myData.Descendants("HelpItems").First();
        helpItems.Add(newitem.XmlHelpItem());

        //then save it back out to the file system
        myData.Save(PhysicalApplicationPath + "/Data.xml");
```

If I want to use this data in an easily managed data set I can bind it to a list of my objects.

```
        List<HelpItem> helpitems = (from helpitem in myData.Descendants("HelpItem")
                  select new HelpItem
                  {
                       Category = helpitem.Element("Category").Value,
                       Question = helpitem.Element("Question").Value,
                       Answer = helpitem.Element("Answer").Value,
                  }).ToList<HelpItem>();
```

Now it can be passed around and manipulated with any inherent functions of my object class.

For convenience my class has a function to create itself as an xml node.

```
public XElement XmlHelpItem()
    {
        XElement helpitem = new XElement("HelpItem");
        XElement category = new XElement("Category", Category);
        XElement question = new XElement("Question", Question);
        XElement answer = new XElement("Answer", Answer);
        helpitem.Add(category);
        helpitem.Add(question);
        helpitem.Add(answer);
        return helpitem;
    }
```

Comment: If I need to query XML like I'm querying other data I agree.  But, for simple validation or forward-only searching XmlReader is the better choice because it is more efficient.

Comment: We have a serious problem when a question titled "How to use XmlReader class" has an accepted answer that doesn't come close to answering the question. I'm voting to remove or rename the question.

Comment: This isn't a good solution if you are reading huge XML documents. XMLReader allows you to stream it and read in pieces.

Answer (score 12):

MSDN has a simple example to get you started [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(VS.95).aspx).

If you're interested in reading and writing XML documents, and not just specifically using the XmlReader class, there's [a nice article covering a few of your options here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli2111282005041517AM/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli21.aspx).

But if you just want to get started and play around, try this:

```
 XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
 settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
 settings.IgnoreComments = true;
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml", settings);
```

Comment: It always surprises me when I find little snippets of code that solve my issue and they are snippets that I couldnt find *anywhere* including the MS site. Thanks, this one saved me.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `Create` method instead of using `new`, since `XmlReader` is an `abstract class` using [the Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

```
var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("xmlfile.xml");
```

Answer (score 6):

From the excellent [C# 3.0 in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527570/), consider looking at the [sample code](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/ch11.aspx) from chapter 11.