# XmlReader.GetAttribute() doesn't throw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Why doesn't `System.Xml.XmlReader.GetAttribute(String)` throw an exception if the attribute is not found?! It seems ridiculous and dangerous at first sight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there's nothing "exceptional" about not finding a specified attribute. What if it's optional? Would you then be relying on thrown exceptions to control your program flow?

This isn't good practice - you should simply check the return value for null before using it.

Comment: +1 - right on...exceptions shouldn't be used for testing conditions

Comment: And what about XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString(string, string) for example? It throws exception in this case. Or element cannot be optional unlike attribute?

Comment: By the way, I'm certainly not going to use exceptions for testing conditions. All of my attributes are required. I think it is much more frequent situation than optional attributes

Comment: "All of my attributes are required. I think it is much more frequent situation than optional attributes". I think you are wrong. Probably neither of us has any quantitative data to use as evidence.

Comment: OK, I was wrong. I thought XmlReader has something like bool HasAttribute(string name) to determine the presence of the attribute. And without such method null from GetAttribute() - it is the only option )

Comment: You probably want to write an XSD to validate your XML document against if correctness of the XML is an issue.

Comment: Thanks, but it is just configuration file containing data serialized by me. I HOPE that it will be correct all the time )))

Comment: @groaner: Slightly on a tangent, but have you thought about using XDocument instead of XmlReader? See the accepted answer on this question for some nice examples of the advantages of doing so; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904129/how-to-use-xmlreader-class

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions shouldn't be used for control-flow.  As Chris McAtackney stated, what if the attribute is optional?  Using exceptions for control flow adds overhead when exceptions are caught due to a missing attribute.  It's better and more efficient to just check for an empty string.